# Want c++ to get these variables into an array from a text file.But I don't know how to specify locations in a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, ifstream, area

I am a newbie in coding and I got a txt file to include them in an array.

The size of the array must be the number at the top. All the other lines are actually coordinates. As you have guessed I need to calculate the area of the polygon there. But I cant actually sit the coordinates inside the array. And also I need to be careful about not including the value at the top of the text into the array. Thanks in advance for anyone reads this!

The text:

6

1000.0, 1000.0

1000.1, 1000.0

1000.2, 1000.1

1000.1, 1000.2

1000.0, 1000.2

1000.0, 1000.1

Answer (score 0):

Just read the values in with `>>`. The only trick is reading the comma into a char variable.

```
file >> size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    double x, y;
    char comma;
    file >> x >> comma >> y;
    // do something with x and y
}
```

Of course there is no error checking in this code. In real code you should add some.